# May i reuse activerecord id after I destroy ?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

```
p = People.first
#p { :id => 1}
p.destroy

s = People.new
#s {:id => 2}
s = p.id
# s.id => 1 
s.save

#real output:  UPDATE peoples set updated_at ='2012.....' WHERE people.id = 2 
#expect output :    UPDATE peoples set updated_at ='2012.....' WHERE people.id = 2
```

I would like to resue the activerecord id after I destroy some id. Is it possiable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But be careful, old link to people profile may route to other profile (old person with `id` 5 was deleted and new person will be with 5)

```
Peson.create(:id => 5)
```

Comment: ActiveRecord usually doesn't allow `:id` to be used in mass-assignment, so you probably need to expand that to `p = Person.new; p.id = 5; p.save`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it, in your above code sample,

`s = p.id` should be `s.id = p.id`

Comment: so , what happen when `s = pid`   and result: `# s.id => 1`  ?  don't understand ..

Comment: `s` is just a reference, when you do `s = p.id`, value of `p.id` will be assigned to `s`. If `p.id` evaluates to 2, integer 2 will be assigned to variable s.

Comment: yes, but when value of `p.id` ( which is 1 ) assigned to `s`.   why irb still return `#s.id => 1` ?  thanks.

Comment: Didn't it should return `#s => 1`  ?